# How to see the changed version of an instance attribute in another method? Python

Tags: python, class, object, oop

I have the following Code

(The class Ship is inheriting from a class called Main)

```
class Ship(Main):
    def __init__(self, ship_x, ship_y, ship_img):
        super().__init__()
        self.enemy_x = ship_x
        self.enemy_y = ship_y
      
        # Amount the enemy will move in x and y direction
        self.enemy_move_x = 2
        self.enemy_move_y = 50
        self.enemy_off_screen = False

    
    def draw_enemy_ship(self):
        self.enemy_ship = self.screen.blit(self.enemy_img, (self.enemy_x, self.enemy_y))
    
    def enemy_ship_movement(self):

        if self.enemy_off_screen == False:
            self.enemy_x += self.enemy_move_x

        if self.enemy_x >= (self.screen_x - (self.enemy_img.get_width())):
            self.enemy_y += self.enemy_move_y
            self.enemy_off_screen = True

        if self.enemy_off_screen == True:
            self.enemy_x -= self.enemy_move_x
            if self.enemy_x <= 1:
                self.enemy_y += self.enemy_move_y
                self.enemy_off_screen = False

        print(f"Enemy x: {self.enemy_x}, Enemy y: {self.enemy_y}")

    def enemy(self):
        self.draw_enemy_ship()
        self.enemy_ship_movement()

    def shoot_laser(self):
       print(f"Enemy x: {self.enemy_x}, Enemy y: {self.enemy_y}")

ship = Ship(2, 1, main.ENEMY_IMG)

ship.enemy()
ship.shoot_laser()
```

Whenever I run the following code the `enemy()` method prints out the correct value of the position of the enemy as it is moving across the screen, however the `shoot_laser()` method always prints out `2` for enemy's x position and `1` for the enemy's y position which are the values which I assigned it when I made an instance of the class.

Is there a way in which I can tell the `shoot_laser()` method to use the modified version of the instance attributes `enemy_x` and `enemy_y` without having to do something like this:

```
def shoot_laser(self):
    self.enemy()
    print(f"Enemy x: {self.enemy_x}, Enemy y: {self.enemy_y}")
```

Comment: well to let shoot_laser to know the modified location you need to modify /save the location of them in self.enemy_x and self.enemy_y, you need to make a function call for it earlier to have the latest location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing the `enemy_x` and `enemy_y` attributes as parameters to the `shoot_laser()` method:

```
def shoot_laser(self, enemy_x, enemy_y):
    print(f"Enemy x: {enemy_x}, Enemy y: {enemy_y}")
```